# Read Excel spreedsheet and display it using Angular material data grid

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using `SheetJS js-xlsx` to read and display excel data my current app version is 7.

Working link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-excel-read-table

So when I tried to install the angular material, excel display is not working any longer.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l-d

Please help.

[image]

Comment: its working.. on your stackblitz.. just scroll down

Comment: no its not `ERROR
Error: Cannot find file [Content_Types].xml in zip` i'm getting this error

Comment: 1st link is working, but 2nd link is not woking

Comment: Its working with 2nd link. Try in incognito

Comment: Can you try with different excel?

Comment: I tried with 2 different excel not working, it was working previously after angular material its throwing this error

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer just screenshot

[image]

Comment: so weird, I just tried it in incognito mode, I still get error in the console

Comment: can you addscreenshot?

Comment: yeah added plz have a look